# Magento2 setup page keeps loading

Tags: php, magento2

I've installed magento 2 on a homestead box. But it keeps loading
on the setup page (domain.test/setup) and it looks like this:[image]

I've run `composer install`, `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload` nothing works. I've tried `apache` and `nxinx` both not working.

What could I try?

Comment: my setup script just kept getting `page isn't redirecting properly` - I did via command line and everything works so.. not sure .. what v of m2 do you have?

Comment: My version is 2.2.4

Comment: same here - definitely think there is a bug with it, but the team on Github closed my ticket saying it was down to server conf - even though, every page works after install, just /setup broke